# push notification flutter in background service

Tags: android, ios, rest, flutter, push-notification

I need run a dart code for each 10s even if the application is closed. It's possible? in flutter

I need to fetch data every 10s if any change the push notification show to the users

i am using a custom API rest (asp.net core) for data connecting

On click of the notification should open the app.

I have not worked on Push Notifications in the past and would be great if you could help me with where to start. Links to any documentation or advice would be great.

Thanks in advance.